# Send DMed files and links to channel in server

Tags: discord, discord.js

Okay. This might be a strange question, but I need help as I could not find anything online. I have a discord bot and server that is hosts a competition, and users submit their submissions by Direct Messaging me a link or file of their submission. I would like to change this to them DMing the bot instead, and the bot posting the links and files in a certain channel in the server. I have absolutely no clue how to achieve this as I am kind of a novice when it comes to this sort of thing. Please comment if I need to change my wording or need to clarify anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `channel id` with the actual id of the channel that you want to send the submissions to.

For Discord.js v12/v13 (the latest version):

```js
client.on('message', ({attachments, author, content, guild}) => {
  // only do this for DMs
  if (!guild) {
    // this will simply send all the attachments, if there are any, or the message content
    // you might also want to check that the content is a link as well
    const submission = attachments.size
      ? {files: [...attachments.values()], content: `${author}`}
      : {content: `${content}\n${author}`}
    client.channels.cache.get('channel id').send(submission)
  }
})
```

For Discord.js v11 replace

```js
client.channels.cache.get('channel id').send(submission)
```

with

```js
client.channels.get('channel id').send(submission)
```

Comment: perfection! Thank you

Comment: is there a way to have this also send the user tag of who sent it?

Answer (score 0):

In the `message` event, you can check if the message is in a dm channel then you can take the message content and send it to a specific channel as an embed.

Your solution would be:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        const channel = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID").channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID");
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setDescription(message.content)

        channel.send(embed);

        if (message.attachments.array().length) {
            message.attachments.forEach((attachment) => channel.send({ files: [ attachment ] }))
        }
    }
})
```